# Solve the boundary of a region

Tags: analysis

A rod of length 1 has endpoints constrained to lie on the positive $x$ and $y$ axes.
With an initial of position of endpoints at $(0,0),(0,1)$, it slides continuously to the
position $(1,0),(0,0)$ sweeping out a region in the positive quadrant. Determine the
equation for the boundary of this region.

I think if we can make a transition to polar coordinates, then we can solve max $r(\theta)$ for every $\theta$. But how to do it? Or do you have other good methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say the bottom of the rod is at $(t,0)$; then in order for the rod to have a constant length of $1$, the other end will be at $(0, \sqrt{1-t^2})$. The equation for the line in terms of $x$ is

$$x = -\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}y+t$$

Fixing $y$ and maximizing $x$ with respect to $t$ (in order to find the highest point above $x$ which the rod touches), we obtain $t = \sqrt{1 - y^{2/3}}$, and so $$x = \sqrt{1-y^{2/3}}(1-\frac{y}{y^{1/3}})=(1-y^{2/3})^{3/2}$$
which is the equation for the boundary

Answer (score 0):

It is the classical sliding ladder problem (http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/ladder.htm)

The envelope (the curve to which all the positions of the ladder are tangent) is an astroid.